# Function-based index on object type

Tags: oracle, indexing, casting, oracle18c, object-type

I have a column in an Oracle 18c table that is an **object type** (user-defined type): [Esri's ST_GEOMETRY spatial type](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/stgeometry-oracle.htm).

I want to create a **function-based index** on that column:

```
create or replace function my_owner.test_func(shape in sde.st_geometry) return sde.st_geometry
deterministic is
begin
    return sde.st_geometry_operators.st_startpoint_f(sde.st_geometry_operators.st_geometryn_f(shape,1)); 
end;

create index my_owner.test_idx on my_owner.active_transportation (my_owner.test_func(shape));
```

I can create the function without issue. But when I try to create the index, it fails:

```
Error starting at line : 10 in command -
create index my_owner.test_idx on my_owner.active_transportation (my_owner.test_func(shape))
Error report -
ORA-02327: cannot create index on expression with datatype ADT
02327. 00000 -  "cannot create index on expression with datatype %s"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to create an index on a non-indexable
           expression.
*Action:   Change the column datatype or do not create the index on an
           expression whose datatype is one of  VARRAY, nested table, object,
           LOB, or  REF.
```

That error seems pretty definitive: Oracle can't create a function-based index on objects.

With that said, are there any workarounds for this scenario?

For example, could I cast the object as something else in the function, create the index on the casting, and then un-cast it in a query?

- For what it's worth, there is a function that can convert the object to a blob. Unfortunately though, blobs aren't supported in function-based indexes either. I get the same error.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [ST_GEOMETRY and SDO_GEOMETRY Interoperability](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/st_geometry-and-sdo_geometry-interoperability.htm#SPATL563) and [SDO_GEOMETRY Objects in Function-Based Indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geometry-objects-function-based-indexes.htm#SPATL799) In principle it seems to be possible.

Comment: Are you trying to create a regular b-tree index?  Or a spatial index?  I'm not sure why you'd want to use a regular b-tree index on a spatial data type so my guess would be that you want to create a spatial index.  But I'm not sure what you intend to use this index for.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, good idea. For clarity, I'm using Esri's version of ST_GEOMETRY, which is different from Oracle's ST_GEOMETRY. But yes, I'm looking into converting to SDO_GEOMETRY in the function/function-based index. With that said, there are some complications and downsides (I can elaborate if needed). So I was hoping to stay within the ST_GEOMETRY realm, if possible.

Comment: @JustinCave Good point. I tried creating a function-based **spatial** index, just like you're suggesting. But I can't get the mapping software (ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro) to actually **use** the spatial index when displaying the points in the map. And I don't see any evidence of SQL Developer using it either — when selecting rows in a query. I talk about the problem issue: [Get map to use ST_GEOMETRY function-based spatial index](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431567/get-map-to-use-st-geometry-function-based-spatial-index). I'm also working with support, but I'm not optimistic. [continued]

Comment: @JustinCave ...So I thought I'd try a regular B-tree index, as an experiment, to see what happens — as a last resort. I'm not sure what it will take to get the map to use an FBI.

Comment: In the thread you linked to, it doesn't appear that you're trying to filter out rows (at least not meaningfully).  It looks like you are just trying to cache the computed value.  A computed column in the table or a materialized view would make more sense for that use case.  Could you use one of those approaches or is there some reason that a function-based index makes more architectural sense in your use case?

Comment: @JustinCave You are correct: *"...It doesn't appear that you're trying to filter out rows (at least not meaningfully). It looks like you are just trying to cache the computed value."* **Question:** When you say *"a computed column...would make more sense"*, are you referring to [Oracle virtual columns](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1)? With virtual columns, is there a way to cache the computed value?

Comment: @User1974 - Is your table an object table?  That would be quite unusual.  It is likely a normal table with an object as the data type of one of the columns.

Comment: @JustinCave You might be interested in this related post: [Intended use case for virtual columns with function-based index?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/312570/intended-use-case-for-virtual-columns-with-function-based-index).